# How can I use Python 3.8 in snaps?

Tags: python, snap, python3, ubuntu-core

As far as I know the only supported Python versions based on `base: core18` are `python2` and `python3`. However `python3` means Python 3.6. How can I use Python 3.8 in snaps?

Comment: Here's how another user solved the same problem for Python 3.7; should apply to your case, too: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-do-i-correctly-install-a-custom-python-version-and-a-local-wheel-package/12040